# declarar constante pasando variável dentro do objeto

Tags: php

Preciso chamar o diretório raiz do meu projeto, apenas a raiz independente de onde o script estiver.

Pesquisando achei o `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` e como boa prática quero passar isso para uma constante dentro de um objeto usando `const`.

```
<?php
class Test{
   const DIROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
```

Entretanto recebo o seguinte erro:

> "Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
>   /var/www/html/sys/php/test.php on line 3"

Se tento declará-la com string pura `const DIROOT = "/exemplo";` funciona. Por que ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não entendi a questão da "boa prática", mas o erro ocorre porquê não é possível inicializar constantes com qualquer valor que não seja uma expressão constante. Vide [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.constants.php):

> O valor deve ser uma expressão constante, não podendo ser (por exemplo) uma variável, uma propriedade, ou uma chamada a uma função.

A expressão constante é apenas um valor, tal como em:

```
const DIROOT = "/exemplo";
```

Ou até uma expressão com valores constantes, ta como:

```
const PI = 3 + 0.14159;
```

Ou com *strings*:

```
const NAME = "Foo" . "Bar";
```

Ou seja, não é possível atribuir uma variável:

```
const DIROOT = $_REQUEST["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]; // erro
```

Ou uma chamada de função:

```
const DIROOT = get_dir_root(); // erro
```

---

Porém, utilizando [`define`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.define.php) você pode fazer algo semelhante ao que deseja:

```
define("DIROOT", $_REQUEST["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

Se é que isso realmente é necessário para sua aplicação.

Comment: Mas a função `define()` so pode estar dentro de métodos no objeto como `__construct()`. Procede ?

Comment: Sim, mas não faz sentido chamá-la dentro da classe. Neste caso seria global.

Comment: define() pode estar em qualquer lugar, mas ela é usada para constantes globais.